# Передача переменной из html в ts

Tags: angular5

есть код компонента 
html:

```
<td><input class="form-control" type="text" #titleForCreateGroup /></td>
<td><button class="btn btn-success"      (click)="create(titleForCreateGroup)">добавить</button></td>
```

ts:

```
....
create(el) {console.log(el.value);}
....
```

Как правильно из html передать переменную в данном случае? Я написал как у меня щас...посоветуйте вариант правильнее.

Comment: с чего вы взяли что этот вариант неправильный?

Comment: @overthesanity это просто вопрос...мне показалось что есть более лучший способ